# How to sync registered users in database with iPhone contacts

Tags: objective-c, database, synchronization, addressbook, whatsapp

Imagine an iphone app that automatically registers users on the first start according to their phone identity (e.g. phone number*) on a server database.
Afterwards, users should see which of their friends already use the app, i.e. which of their contacts are registered on the DB.
An obvious solution would be to always send a select-request to the DB containing all of the users contacts, everytime the user refreshs his or her friend list. As a result, the user retrieves the list of their registered contacts (friends).
Is there any better way to realize this synchronization between the user management on the server and the contacts in the user's address book. Sending multiple select-requests (each user for every refresh) with dozens of phone numbers might not be performant at all.

***Example:***
WhatsApp is actually a good example for this scenario. You can add new contacts to your address book and WhatsApp automatically refreshs your WhatsApp friend list according to your phone book. I really like this idea because the user don't need to create an account manually.

*I know about the problems of using phone numbers in AppStore apps, so this question really focusses on the architectural problem.

**EDIT**

this comment ([Whatsapp contacts syncronization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17339872/whatsapp-contacts-syncronization/17340813#17340813)) describes the mentioned simple approach. but is this really the smartest way?